# Filter data in Firebase by follows

Tags: android, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Firebase database:
[image]

I would like to create an Android app where everybody can posts short texts. However, on the main screen I would like to show only those posts from other users who I followed. On the example, this means that if I logged in like Mrs. Nobody into the app, I can see only the first post created by Mr. Nobody.

Is that possible? (I tried to receive every posts in "posts" and after that I could show only posts what are relevant for me, but data traffic was really high in this case)

I have another idea, but I try to find a more efficient one. My idea is to receive every relations from "relations" where follow_uid is mine. After that, I iterate through all the elements and I download those posts where uid is equals with the uid from "relations"

Comment: What you'd trying to model is close to the Firefeed sample app. While the code hasn't been updated for The latest Firebase releases, the data model is still a great example. See https://firefeed.io/about.html

Comment: You see that his application writes the posts from Mr. Nobody to Mrs. Nobody's feed when he posts. This is called fanning out the data, you're duplicating data to speed up read operations. It's a model that Twitter was famous for at the time (I don't think they wrote anything about their data model since), but very counter-intuitive to most SQL-educated developers.